# Pytest: 27 Assertion Error: How to format the input and output parameters properly

Tags: python, pytest

I've seen similar questions to this but I can't figure it out for my own example, I have this code:

```
import ast
import pytest
import re

def autocomplete1(str,list_name):
    return [i for i in list(set(list_name)) if i.startswith(str)]


def autocomplete2(str,list_name):
    return(list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(str), list(set(list_name)))))


def autocomplete3(str,list_name):
    return([i for i in list_name if re.match(str,i)])


#fix the list
@pytest.mark.parametrize('input1, input2, output1', [('de',['dog','deer','deal'],['deer','deal']), ('ear',['earplug','earphone','airplane'],['earplug','earphone'])])
def test_function(input1,input2,output1):
    assert autocomplete1(input1,input2) == output1
    assert autocomplete2(input1,input2) == output1
    assert autocomplete3(input1,input2) == output1


The Error is:
start_query_string.py FF                                                                                                                                                                      [100%]

============================================================================================= FAILURES ==============================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________________ test_function[de-input20-output10] _________________________________________________________________________________

input1 = 'de', input2 = ['dog', 'deer', 'deal'], output1 = ['deer', 'deal']

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('input1, input2, output1', [('de',['dog','deer','deal'],['deer','deal']), ('ear',['earplug','earphone','airplane'],['earplug','earphone'])])
    def test_function(input1,input2,output1):
>       assert autocomplete1(input1,input2) == output1
E    AssertionError: assert ['deal', 'deer'] == ['deer', 'deal']
E      At index 0 diff: 'deal' != 'deer'
E      Use -v to get the full diff

start_query_string.py:27: AssertionError
________________________________________________________________________________ test_function[ear-input21-output11] ________________________________________________________________________________

input1 = 'ear', input2 = ['earplug', 'earphone', 'airplane'], output1 = ['earplug', 'earphone']

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('input1, input2, output1', [('de',['dog','deer','deal'],['deer','deal']), ('ear',['earplug','earphone','airplane'],['earplug','earphone'])])
    def test_function(input1,input2,output1):
>       assert autocomplete1(input1,input2) == output1
E    AssertionError: assert ['earphone', 'earplug'] == ['earplug', 'earphone']
E      At index 0 diff: 'earphone' != 'earplug'
E      Use -v to get the full diff

start_query_string.py:27: AssertionError
```

I've tried slightly editing the code in different ways (e.g. turning the input in a tuple) but I'd like to understand how to get this version working so I know what I'm doing wrong. Could someone show me what's wrong?

Comment: If the issue is with the list elements being in the wrong order, perhaps the `sorted` method applied to the lists could resolve the issue

Comment: What's wrong is that sets don't guarantee same order so when you convert the set into a list it gets all messed up. If you're using a set to avoid duplicates, then why don't you just make your input and output assertions using sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that in *autocomplete1* and *autocomplete2* - *set* is unordered type so
there is two ways, as I see it, for function to return predictable results:

1. Sort list after all manipulations will be done (btw there is no need to do `list(set(list_name))`, you can iterate over *set*)
2. If you need specific order you can use OrderedDict

   ```
   from collections import OrderedDict
   l = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 2, 1]
   result = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(l))
   print(result) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   ```

Full working code is

```
import ast
import pytest
import re
from collections import OrderedDict


def autocomplete1(str,list_name):
    return [i for i in list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(list_name)) if i.startswith(str)]


def autocomplete2(str,list_name):
    return(list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(str), list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(list_name)))))


def autocomplete3(str,list_name):
    return([i for i in list_name if re.match(str,i)])


#fix the list
@pytest.mark.parametrize('input1, input2, output1', [('de',['dog','deer','deal'],['deer','deal']), ('ear',['earplug','earphone','airplane'],['earplug','earphone'])])
def test_function(input1,input2,output1):
    assert autocomplete1(input1,input2) == output1
    assert autocomplete2(input1,input2) == output1
    assert autocomplete3(input1,input2) == output1
```